# Удаление "ссылок" из истории браузера

Tags: windows, браузер

**Предыстория**

История накопилась приличная, в добавок ещё и синхронизация включена.
Чтобы хоть как-то "уменьшить объём" истории, решил удалить какие-то бесполезные сайты оттуда, допустим VK (>23к ссылок в истории)

**Проблема**

Если в поиске вбить `vk.com` - то выдаст все сайты, это логично, при выделение всех (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) получаем больше 23 тысяч ссылок, нажимаем <kbd>Delete</kbd> - ложится браузер.
Весело, неправда ли?

**Вопрос**

Удалять вручную, долго и муторно.
Есть ли какие-нибудь варианты?
Допустим наличие папки в системе?
Код какой-нибудь? :D

Использую Mozilla, Windows x64

---

Чую щас минусы полетят.

Comment: В %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ живут профили. Там должен быть файл со словом history в названии и расширением подразумевающим бд

Comment: @Talleyran, по данному адресу, внутри, ничего связанного с history нет :с

Comment: все историю почистить совесть не позволяет?

Comment: @michael_best, многие ссылки используются, особенно когда в адресную строку ввожу что-то.

Comment: нашел чудо http://www.verim.org/project/comp/tonkaja_nastrojka_mozilla_firefox тут опция browser.history_expire_sites - срок хранения данных с сайтов.

Comment: попробуйте поставить для vk.com - 0

Comment: @michael_best, вот за статью спасибо! Почитаю на досуге и настрою.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый способ рабочий, но оказался не рабочим для Вас.
Есть 2 вариант, редачить sqlite.
Он рабочий, но до конца я с ним не разобрался, по сути по каждому вашему визиту по определенным ссылкам- создается уникальный ID, это сделано для того, чтобы вывести "самые посещаемые сайты". Потому надо будет сначала сделать как сейчас я расскажу, а после использовать 1 вариант, но по сути, должно сработать.

---

**[ 1 ]** Щёлкните по кнопке меню > Справка > Информация для решения проблем > Ищем кнопку "Открыть папку" в разделе "Сведения о приложении".

---

В итоге- мы открыли папку с вашим профилем, который вы сейчас используете.

Запомните, **`places.sqlite`** это и есть бд со всеми данными(история, закладки и т.п.)

---

**[ 2 ]** Качаем программу для редактирования формата `sqlite`, я выбрал `DB Browser`-первая какая попалась+с нормальным функционалом.
(ссылка на скачку: [>>x32(86)<<](https://cdn.softwareclub.ru/DB.Browser.for.SQLite-3.10.1-win32.exe)  | [>>x64<<](https://cdn.softwareclub.ru/DB.Browser.for.SQLite-3.10.1-win64.exe) ) 
P.S разместил у себя на веб сервере. Для недоверчивых-([>>VTx32<<](https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/56d390db765a04ff49c7ee606e6f36cdefd8d0abcfcb6913f66f0088dc0f0223/detection) |[>>VTx64<<](https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/8af07dd510f172efe76c687ed0922107fe45c00c7137837d664002e5da45259a/detection)), ну или качайте с офф.сайта.

---

**[ 2.5 ]** Устанавливаем, после чего копируем путь который мы открыли **(1 шаг,если что)**
(если кто не знал, кликаем по полю, и `CTRL+A` and `CTRL+C`)

[image: Кликать сюда]

---

**[ 3 ]** Заходим в программу, нажимаем "Открыть базу данных", и вставляем путь, который скопировали> нажимаем "Открыть", после чего у вас будет каталог, в том каталоге ищем `places.sqlite` > Открываем

---

**[ 4 ]** Нажимаем "Данные">Выбираем `moz-places` в выпадающем списке с БД (либо в начальном окне правой кнопкой в Таблицах на `moz-places`>Просмотр данных)

---

**[ 5 ]** В поле "Фильтр"(url) ищем ваш сайт

---

**[ 6 ]** Выделяем всё (`CTRL+A`) и сверху над поиском есть кнопка "Удалить запись" (Не используйте Delete- т.к. не удалит таблицы)

---

**[ 7 ]** Так как ваши заходы на сайт(а точнее их количество) храниться, вам прийдеться снова зайти на сайт, и воспользоваться моим способом(который я показал выше)

---

Answer (score 3):

Все есть встроено, далеко ходить не пришлось)

Заходим в **Настройки>Библиотека>Журнал>Показать весь журнал>Выбираем сайт который хотим удалить(правой кнопкой мыши)>забыть сайт**

**В картинках**

---

**Настройки**

[image: Настройки]

**Библиотека**


[image: Библиотека]

**Журнал**

[image: Журнал]

**Показать весь журнал**

[image: Показать весь журнал]

**ПКМ и забыть сайт**


[image: ПКМ и забыть сайт]

---

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так оно потом перестанет сохранять историю

Comment: Нет, у меня всё сохраняет
http://prntscr.com/mfepc1

Comment: Я попробовал данный способ, я очистил им историю по данному сайт (пришлось подождать), но суть в том, что это аналогичный метод тому, что я указал в вопросе => и проблема та же (браузер полёг).